# How do you get a list of all the installed fonts?

Tags: .net, fonts

Specifically in .NET, but I'm leaving it open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MSDN:

[Enumerating Installed Fonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yf5t4e8(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yf5t4e8.aspx

This should help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is InstalledFontCollection.
(What were the chances that the ONE piece of code that required .net would be relevant to anything here! It boggles the mind!)