# Test if a font is installed (Win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

How can I test if a font is installed?

Ultimately, I want to implement a HTML-like font selection, i.e. when specifying e.g. "Verdana,Arial", it should pick the first font that is installed.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113989/test-if-a-font-is-installed) provides an answer for .NET - it seems the recommended way is to create the font, and then cmpare the font face actually used.

Is that the most efficient way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use EnumFontFamiliesEx to enumerate the list of Fonts on the system, or if you pass a font name you can enumerate the fonts for that family.

Comment: Do you know what is the point of the DC parameter to EnumFonts et al.? It isn't required in CreateFont. Passing the Desktop Window's DC seems to work, but I can't find any documentation (except the "handle to the device context") in MSDN

Comment: I suspect it might be for when using a printer dc but I have only ever used GetDC(NULL) and have never tried anything else.

Comment: The DC will restrict the fonts enumerated to ones available to the device.  Nowadays, that's not much of a restriction.  You don't need a DC when you call CreateFont, because CreateFont just creates an internal version of a LOGFONT and gives you a handle to it.  Only when you select that handle into a DC will the actual font be chosen and instantiated.

Answer (score 6):

You can either try to create the font and see what you get (thus using the OS's font name matching/substitution).

Or you can enumerate installed fonts and do that matching yourself.

The "most efficient" way will depend on the details of a "match", and, in all likelihood, how many fonts are installed. On a system with, say, 50 fonts you will probably find performance is significantly different to a system with 1000 fonts installed.

In the end you can only profile on representative systems, if you first approach (keep it simple) turns out to be a performance bottleneck.