# Why is there no exception if using not existing font?

Tags: c#, .net, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test if a Font is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113989/test-if-a-font-is-installed)

let say Im using an installed font on the system:

```
new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 120F);
```

everything is fine. Now if I would use a not existing font:

```
new System.Drawing.Font("IdoNotExistHaHa", 120F);
```

I dont get any exception. As I see, if I use a font that doesnt exist I get a standard font (arial?, not sure). Whatever, I would like to throw an exception if there is a not found font. How to?

Comment: @Mr.Steak: no relation. The question is: why I didn't get any notification that form doesn't exist, and not *how* to check if font present. Those questions *may* be realted, but not it's not esplicitly manifested in *this* question.

Comment: @Tigran - " I would like to throw an exception if there is a not found font." since the throwing of an exception will require some form of test for if the font is available, there's more than a little overlap.

Comment: @Tigran The question I linked contains the solution to the underlying problem. The question 'How to throw an exception if there is a not found font?' *is* checking if the font is installed or not, then you can throw an exception yourself. Otherwise, if the OP would only be interested in *why* the constructor of `System.Drawing.Font` does not throw an exception, the question should be closed as 'not constructive'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN says as following :

> For more information about how to construct fonts, see How to:
>   Construct Font Families and Fonts.  Windows Forms applications support
>   TrueType fonts and have limited support for OpenType fonts. If you
>   attempt to use a font that is not supported, or the font is not
>   installed on the machine that is running the application, the
>   Microsoft Sans Serif font will be substituted.

You can check the if the font is correct by doing as following :

```
var myFont = new Font(fontName)
if (myFont.Name != fontName ) 
{ 
    throw new Exception()
}
```

Comment: should I not try !myFont.Name.Equals(fontName)?

Answer (score 2):

You can see it in documentation itself, [Font Constructor (String, Single)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/164w6x6z.aspx)

> Windows Forms applications support TrueType fonts and have limited
> support for OpenType fonts. If the familyName parameter specifies a
> font that is not installed on the machine running the application or
> is not supported, Microsoft Sans Serif will be substituted.

In short, *default* font is `Microsoft Sans Serif`

Answer (score 1):

You could check and see if the font is installed first.
From Jeff Hillman's answer here: [Test if a Font is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113989/test-if-a-font-is-installed)

```
string fontName = "Consolas";
float fontSize = 12;

Font fontTester = new Font( 
fontName, 
fontSize, 
FontStyle.Regular, 
GraphicsUnit.Pixel );

if ( fontTester.Name == fontName )
{
    // Font exists
}
else
{
    // Font doesn't exist
}
```

Obviously, you could then throw an exception if you wanted(as that is your original question), although I would recommend not to, throwing an exception is an expensive operation if you can handle the issue more gracefully without.

Comment: should I not use fontTester.Name.Equals(fontName)?

Comment: @silla Thats a different question all together :) Generally == is considered acceptable usage for strings; take a look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx