# How to determine string is a valid font when converting?

Tags: c#, fonts, type-conversion

I am converting a string to a Font using this approach:

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));
return (Font) converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(textValue);
```

I was hoping it would raise an exception if the textValue was an invalid font but it seems to just return a default font. How can I determine if the string is indeed a valid font?

Comment: I hope this Answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113989/test-if-a-font-is-installed

Comment: No, not really. To do that I would basically need to parse the string myself.