# More easy way to show if a Font is installed or not

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I'm using this code and works fine

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text

Dim fontInstalled As Boolean = False
Dim fontToSearch As String
Dim fonts As New InstalledFontCollection

fontToSearch = "Verdana"

For Each one As FontFamily In fonts.Families
        'If I want to show every installed family name
        'MsgBox(one.Name)
        If one.Name = fontToSearch Then
            fontInstalled = True
            MsgBox("Font " & fontToSearch & " IS installed!!!")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

If fontInstalled = False Then MsgBox("Font " & fontToSearch & " is NOT installed")
```

**But I'm sure there will be a cleaner solution using InstalledFontCollection or something but I can't adapt this code to VB.NET [Test if a Font is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113989/test-if-a-font-is-installed)**

```
var fontsCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();
foreach (var fontFamiliy in fontsCollection.Families)
{
if (fontFamiliy.Name == fontName) ... \\ installed
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use the keyword `New` , check to see if it includes a `Dispose` method.  If it does, it means that it likely allocates some resource which needs to be `Disposed`.  So, use it in a `Using` block

**1. Check if installed**

```
Dim IsInstalled As Boolean

Using fnts As New InstalledFontCollection()
    IsInstalled = fnts.Families.
                AsEnumerable().
                Select(Function(s) s.Name).
                Contains("Verdana")
End Using
```

**2. Try It**

```
Using fnt As New Font("Verdana", 12)
    IsInstalled = (fnt IsNot Nothing)
End Using
```

**3. Get List of Installed Names**

```
Dim fontNames As String()
Using fnts As New InstalledFontCollection()
    fontNames = fnts.Families.
                AsEnumerable().
                Select(Function(s) s.Name).
                ToArray()
End Using
```

**Bonus Tip**

`MsgBox` / `MessageBox` is a horrible way to debug.  From the menu select **Debug | Windows | Output**.  You can dock this where ever you want and set it to "Auto Hide" so it hides unless the mouse is over it.  To output to it:

```
For Each s As String In fontNames
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

*et voila* no more clicking to dispose of 172 font name dialogs.

Comment: Worked fine thanks. Also your answer is a complete tutorial with tips. I still have vices of misuse of old Visual Basic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A check like this may help:

```
imports system.drawing.text
...
Function IsFontInstalled(FontName As String) As Boolean
    Dim fonts As New InstalledFontCollection
    For Each one As FontFamily In fonts.Families
        If one.Name = FontName Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

---

Ran across this technique:

```
Function IsFontInstalled(FontName As String) As Boolean

    Using fnt As New Font(FontName, 12)
        Return (fnt IsNot Nothing)
    End Using

End Function
```

So short you could use the technique in line.

Comment: Worked great and really elegant solution. Thanks.