# How to test if a Font is installed?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, fonts

I'm having trouble determining if a custom font (Euclid Triangle) is installed on a collection of machines.

I've used the code listed here
"[Test if a Font is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113989/test-if-a-font-is-installed)" and it works on my Windows 10 machine. But it does not work on a Windows 7 machine and a bunch of machines at my customer.

All machines have .Net 4.5 and above.

The font is not listed if I try listing all the Fonts on the machine:

```
    static void ListFonts()
    {
        try
        {
            using (InstalledFontCollection fontsCollection = new InstalledFontCollection())
            {
                FontFamily[] fontFamilies = fontsCollection.Families;
                var fonts = new List<string>();
                foreach (FontFamily font in fontFamilies)
                    fonts.Add(font.Name);
                var file = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Path() + "\\fonts.txt");
                Serializer.SerializeToFile(fonts, file.FullName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Printer Configuration", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            var file = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Path() + "\\log.txt");
            File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, ex.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I've run my code as Administrator to confirm that the issue is not related to permissions.

Comment: Just guessing: insufficient rights on other machines?

Comment: Your code does not search for a particular font, it only adds them to a list, and writes it to a file…

Comment: I know the code that I listed doesn't search for a particular font.. The post that i link to contains numerous examples of that - i have tried them all and none work on the target machines.

Comment: So if I read your edited post correctly, you say the font is installed (i.e. can be used from, say, WordPad) but does not show when you list the fonts using the code?

Comment: Correct. The font appears in MS Word etc and can be used. The font cannot be found when listing the fonts via code.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ, iterating the list of installed fonts and checking whether it contains a particular one should be essentially a one-liner (plus the inevitable boilerplate):

```
static bool IsFontInstalled(string fontname)
{
    using (var ifc = new InstalledFontCollection())
    {
        return ifc.Families.Any(f => f.Name == fontname);
    }
}
```

Comment: The post that i link to contains your example - i have tried it and it doesn't work on the target machines.