# System.Drawing.Font not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, format, rtf

I'm trying to use a private font (PrivateFontCollection) to change a RichTextBox font. The problem is, the program recognizes the font when I pass the path to it but, when I change the RTB font, it doesn't work and instead it uses *Calibri*.

The code is very simple:

```
var RTB = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();

var privateFont = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
privateFont.AddFontFile(@"path.ttf");

RTB.SelectAll();
RTB.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(privateFont.Families[0], 12);
```

I'm using it to format a RTF text file. When I generate the file it comes out with the Calibri font. And what intrigues me the most is, if I change the `privateFont.AddFontFile(@"path.ttf");`
to *Arial*, for example, the text is returned in the font I wanted, but not the whole text, the end of the text is returned in *Calibri*.

I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: As I understand the docs a PrivateFontCollection is meant to be used by your application only. I doubt that any of its fonts will be available, e.g. in your rtf file..

Comment: @TaW good call! Since I was already somewhat obsessed with `PrivateFontCollection` for things like [Can Fontello glyph be used for Winforms button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72551287/5438626) I appreciate that your comment forced me to think about what would be required if one wanted to export a document using said font in the manner described by OP. Maybe someone will slam dunk a solution to this, but in the meantime the hope is that this answer provides a little room to work with.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question of "what is happening here", for a font to be recognized in an exported RTF file requires that the font either be installed as a system font *or* manually embedded in the file that you are exporting from the `RichTextBox`. The former seems less dicey and the three ways I know of to make the font be installed  are:

- **Manual -** Right-click on **yourcustomfont.ttf** and select **Install**.
- **Deploy -** If your application is packaged in something like an .msi then your installer should be able to install fonts. (This is something I've actually done in the past and I know from my own experience that it works).
- **Proposed solution -** Using this answer [How to test if a Font is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53006947/5438626) run a one-time font installation when the `MainForm` ctor is initially run. The code below checks for the presence of a font named **smiley.ttf** and invokes this Windows system installer dialog if it's not:

[image: Windows font installer]

**TESTBENCH**

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "Fonts", "smiley.ttf");
    privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(path);

    var fontFamily = privateFontCollection.Families[0];
    Debug.Assert(fontFamily.Name == "smiley", "Expecting 'smiley' is the font family name");

    var font = new Font(fontFamily, 12F);

    richTextBox1.Text = "\uE800";
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    richTextBox1.Select(0, 1);
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = font;

    var privateFontName = font.Name;
    // Returns INCORRECT name of private font
    var selectionFontName = richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Name;
    // Returns CORRECT name of private font.
    var selectionOriginalFontName = richTextBox1.SelectionFont.OriginalFontName;

    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
    richTextBox1.AppendText($"PrivateFont={privateFontName}{Environment.NewLine}");
    richTextBox1.AppendText($"SelectionFont.Name={selectionFontName}{Environment.NewLine}");
    richTextBox1.AppendText($"SelectionFont.OriginalFontName={selectionOriginalFontName}{Environment.NewLine}");
    richTextBox1.Select(int.MaxValue, 0);

    // But the private font name is read back correctly
    // when its used for the Font property of a RichTextBox
    richTextBox2.Font = font;
    richTextBox2.AppendText($"Font={richTextBox2.Font.Name}");
    richTextBox2.SelectAll();
    richTextBox2.SelectionFont = richTextBox1.Font;
    richTextBox2.Select(int.MaxValue, 0);   

    if(!IsFontInstalled("smiley"))
    {
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
    }

    // Now test to see if private font is available in the doc
    File.WriteAllText("output.rtf", richTextBox1.Rtf);
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", "output.rtf");
}
PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
```

---

*Regardless of whether or not it gets installed as a system font* the private font is in memory and can be shown to work properly in the `RichTextBox` itself:

[image: main form]

---

However, the result of exporting and opening the file in **Wordpad** or **Word** (tested both) *does* depend on whether the font is installed in the system or not:

[image: Wordpad A-B]

---

Technically speaking, both the [RTF spec](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#:%7E:text=RTF%20supports%20embedded%20fonts%20with,contained%20in%20the%20%5Cfontfile%20group.) and the [openxml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.presentation.embeddedfontlist?view=openxml-2.8.1) (for MS Word) support embedded fonts but I keep reading things that say that they tend to get stripped out if you're *not* opening the RTF file in an **MS Office** product. Being clearly off the deep end with the topic by now, I made a Word doc, embedded the **smiley.ttf** font using the Save options in MS Word, exported it to RTF, and then tested it by *uninstalling* the font in the Windows Personalization settings. Even though I can clearly see the font embed when I inspect the RTF text of the document IT DID NOT WORK when I tried it. So, IMO I wouldn't recommend embedding the font and would use one of the above strategies to install it on the deployed device instead.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/rtb_private_font.git) this testbench.